# PHP pcntl_fork in a foreach loop

Tags: php, multithreading

I have a for each loop is run from an array of around 60,000 strings which is read from a file
For each of these strings I want to run a small python file with the string as an argument.
To speed things up my plan was to run each execution as a separate thread.
I tried the below but this meant that each child carried on the full foreach loop.

```
foreach($namesas $name)
{
    pcntl_fork();
    echo ++$count."\n";
    exec("python script.py -argument:".$name);
}
```

How can I make each name run as a seperate thread? but then not continue with the main foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pcntl_fork()` creates a copy of the script which is at the same point of execution as the parent, as you've noticed.

You can check to see if this script is the parent or the child by checking the return of `pcntl_fork()`:

```
foreach($namesas $name)
{
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if(!$pid){
        //We are the child
        echo ++$count."\n";
        exec("python script.py -argument:".$name);
        break;//Jump out of loop in this child. Parent will continue.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45966/1964163 -- but if you really want to use pcntl_fork, you need to check its return value to see whether or not you're the child process. There's example code on the PHP doc page for pcntl_fork.

Comment: ...however, wanted to add: you've got a threadbomb in the making. You'll probably want to limit yourself to a smaller-than-60,000 number of simultaneous processes.

Comment: @asmecher - how would we limit it to less than 60000 processes?

Comment: You could use pcntl_waitpid (http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-waitpid.php) and code the loop so that no more than a small number of threads run at a time. But you can probably find a library that does this work for you rather than re-inventing the wheel.